# Exception handling in a @testset in Julia

Tags: julia

what is the prefered way to investigate or print out further detail (print input variable of a function, iteration number, etc.) of a failed @test inside a @testset?
I tried to wrap a try-catch-block around it. However, it doesn't seem to fire.

Here is a made-up example:

```
using Base.Test
rng = MersenneTwister(3231);

# define function that works different than expected
function compare(a,b)
    if a == 3 && b == 3
        return false
    else
        return a == b
    end
end

# test function in a test set
@testset "Test Compare Function" begin
    for iii = 1:10
        number = rand(rng,1:10)
        try
            @test compare(number,number) == true
        catch
            @show(number)
        end
    end
end
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure it tests after the printing.

```
@testset "Test Compare Function" begin
    for iii = 1:10
        number = rand(rng,1:10)
        @test begin
             res = compare(number,number) == true
             if !res
                 @show number
                 flush(STDOUT)
             end
             res
        end
    end
end
```